# User filter in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

```
$args = array(
            'role'  => 'customer',
            'meta_query' =>array(
            array(
                    'key' => 'email',
                    'value' => 'abc',
                    'compare' => 'LIKE'
                )
            )
        );




$customers  = get_users($args);
```

I am filtering users using meta query but it does not filter. I get a empty result and there are email ids with "abc" in it. Dont know where am I going wrong.

Comment: use `meta_compare` instead of `compare`. do like this:- `$args = array(
            'role'  => 'customer',
            'meta_query' =>array(
    'key' => 'email',
    'value' => 'abc',
    'meta_compare' => 'LIKE'
   )
        );`

Comment: @YO YO, Please check my answer.

Comment: @AlivetoDie tried , does not work

Comment: @YoYo What version of WordPress are you using?

Comment: @YO YO, We assume that your meta_key='email' and meta_value='abc' in  wp_usermeta  table?

Comment: @YO YO please check my updated code, and replay your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code for your custom query:

```
<?php 
$args = array(
    'role' => 'customer',
    'meta_query'       => array(
        array(
            'key'          => 'email',
            'value'        => 'abc',
            'meta_compare' => 'LIKE',
        )         
    ),
); 
$my_user_query = new WP_User_Query($args);
$editors = $my_user_query->get_results(); 

if ( ! empty( $editors ) ) {

    echo '<ul class="editors-list">';        
        foreach ( $editors as $editor ) {
            $editor_info = get_userdata( $editor->ID );
            echo '<li>' . $editor_info->display_name . '</li>';     
        } 
    echo '</ul>'; 
} else {     
    echo __( 'No editors found!', 'wordpress' ); 
}
```

Please check updated code:

Comment: @YOYO  I have tested above code, it working fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**meta_query** - An array that is handled through to the WP_Meta_Query object. Ref: - https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_users

```
$meta_query_args = array(
                    'key' => 'email',
                    'value' => 'abc',
                    'compare' => 'LIKE'
                );
$meta_query = new WP_Meta_Query( $meta_query_args );
$args = array(
            'role' => 'customer',
            'meta_query' =>array($meta_query )
        );
$customers  = get_users($args);
```